# Debugging PHP

Tags: php, debugging, xdebug

I've been using xdebug to debug and understand code in php projects for a while now, and have sometimes come into situations where it's been unclear what's going on inside of PHP.

Is it possible to set xdebug or gdb up so that i can trace into actual php builtin functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a macosx, solaris or recent freebsd system you can throw a little dtrace at it.    It can come in handy for those all too numerous "WTF is PHP doing?" moments.

Comment: a quick google turned up http://blogs.sun.com/bmc/entry/dtrace_and_php_demonstrated - if you have more pointers to get started, please post them

Comment: nothing specific, I wasn't aware of that link, thanks.     I've had some problems where tracing all filesystem calls from php were enough.  Specifically looking for fopens and flocks.   Turns out PHP doesn't like include_once/require_once declarations (it's not a use (perl)/import (java) replacement like I was treating it).  Too many referenced files would cause a death by flock.

Comment: Oh, this was a good resource.  http://www.brendangregg.com/DTrace/dtrace_oneliners.txt

Answer (score 1):

I doubt it, xdebug is intended for tracing your PHP code, not the internals.  The internals are assumed to be bug-free (which obviously they aren't sometimes, but that's beyond the scope of xdebug).

You can always look at the PHP source if you want to know what the built-in functions do, but that's sometimes pretty hairy.  The PHP manual docs have always served me well enough when I want to know what they'll do.

Answer (score 1):

You can use gdb to trace in to the C-level code, provided you have php compiled with debug symbols. Have a look here for a start:

http://derickrethans.nl/phps_segmentation_faults_gdbfu.php

Answer (score 1):

One way to test the output of the Zend engine, to peek inside at the opcodes, you can use **[Derick Rethan's VLD](http://derickrethans.nl/vld.php) (Vulcan Logic Dissasembler)**, which also appears to be on [PECL](http://pecl.php.net/package/vld). *Note:* only works on *nix systems (see site for requirements).

Some examples of debugging these opcodes can be found on [Sara Golemon's blog](http://blog.libssh2.org/index.php?/categories/1-PHP), in articles such as [Understanding Opcodes](http://blog.libssh2.org/index.php?/archives/92-Understanding-Opcodes.html) and [How long is a piece of string?](http://blog.libssh2.org/index.php?/archives/28-How-long-is-a-piece-of-string.html).

Answer (score 1):

There is also great Google Chrome extension [PHP Console](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/php-console/nfhmhhlpfleoednkpnnnkolmclajemef) with [php library](https://github.com/barbushin/php-console/#php-console-server-library)  that allows to:

- See errors & exception in Chrome JavaScript console & in notification popups.
- Dump any type variable.
- Execute PHP code remotely.
- Protect access by password.
- Group console logs by request.
- Jump to error file:line in your text editor.
- Copy error/debug data to clipboard (for testers).

Recommend to everyone!