# View php process live

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on fixing a wordpress site that's very slow. I need a way to see what php is doing while creating the page. I'm able to do this with visual studio and asp.net. Is there a similar tool for php?

Comment: I think you mean a step-debugger, so you can follow the trails while the application runs, inspect values etc.. In PHP there is xdebug it works with many IDEs: http://xdebug.org/ ; http://xdebug.org/docs/remote

Comment: possible duplicate of [Debugging PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/813783/debugging-php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're looking for a PHP Profiler like http://xdebug.org/docs/profiler

Answer (score 0):

I tried to move your question to the more appropriate [wordpress.stackexchange.com](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com), but it didn't showed on the possible topic sites in my list.

It looks like your problem is the same as the one answered on [this thread on wordpress.stackexchange.com](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/828/profiling-a-wordpress-website-for-deployment-on-shared-hosting)